# NHibernate.InstantiationException could not load test type: <Foo>

Tags: windows, asp.net-mvc-3, fluent-nhibernate

we have an MVC 3.0 project with a quite big domain. The domain access the database via Fluent NHibernate 3.0.

The project is in production since several month, with no problem at all.

Today we are developing a Windows Service accessing the same domain in order to perform some batch operation. 
NHibernate could not initialize given the following error

```
NHibernate.InstantiationException could not load test type: <Foo>
Inner Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

The internet site it still working flowlessy.

According to infos found in internet this problem rises when there are some Property whiting POCO having initialization in the ctor. In effect there are many of these in the domain, but the question is, why MVC poject doesn't explode and win32 does with the same domain?

Stefano

Comment: Do the nhibernate logs show anything useful?  Maybe compare the two log files (one from the web and one from service) and see if there are any noticeable differences in the initialization of nhibernate.  Maybe post your initialization of your session factory.  I'm assuming the error occurs when you initialize your session factory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NHibernate error message was totally misleading because 
it was a value not present in the applicationConfig section of app.configm that had nothing to do with NHibernate or the mapping.

This is for future reference if anyone will find a similar problem.